# How does Access Point recruitment work in Metal Gear Solid Peace Walker?

Tags: psp, metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

In **Metal Gear Solid Peace Walker**, when you attempt to recruit via Access Point Scan you are prompted to turn the Wifi Switch on. When you do that the Wifi light lights up indicating that wifi is being used on the PSP.

What is going on?

The only clue I have is that with more Wifi points nearby more recruits show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to "bring the game to life," so to speak.

Part of the success factors in recruiting via AP is the signal strength and number of the hot spots around you.

The device is not actually searching the internet, but they want you to feel like you the game world is connected to the real world.